# vim screen restore

Tags: ssh, vim, gnu-screen, xterm

i use vim in screen for development and if i quit vim, the current screen-content stays there...

outside the screen (xterm), exiting vim will restore the previous buffer
(like:

```
[ server1 ]~$ cmd
      some stuff, some stuff
[ server1 ]~$ cmd
[ server1 ]~$ cmd
```

)

But not inside screen.

I tried to use xterm as terminal inside screen - but not with the wanted effect.

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the file .screenrc in your home directory, add the line:

> altscreen on

That should fix it. According to the man page for screen, it turns on "alternate screen" support, "just like in xterm."

I tested it out, and it does what you're looking for.

Comment: This only works for new screens. If you want this to apply to an existing screen, you have to execute it as a command, doing: `C-a :` `altscreen on`