# how to refresh entire screen in putty

Tags: remote-access, redhat, putty, tty

I have a redhat machine which I use remotely using putty and this is what have been bugging me a lot now...

Each time I open and close a file with any editor, my prompt shows up on the bottom line without the content of the screen being refreshed. This is really problematic because then I can't see previous outputs that were on the screen just before I opened that file which is still showing up after closing.

Is there a way to fix this. I want it to behave like the gnome-terminal. I don't think this use to happen when I was using an ubuntu server.

I understand that this is the traditional tty behavior, but I don't want it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `screen`?

Comment: Yes I am but it happen without using screen also

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim screen restore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681034/vim-screen-restore)

Comment: Hey thanks that works great for screen. But any idea on how I can get it  to work the same way without screen as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your terminal supports an alternate screen buffer, it should have `rmcup` and `smcup` define in its terminfo entry

```
% infocmp | grep -e rmcup -e smcup
    ri=\EM, rmacs=^O, rmcup=\E[2J\E[?47l\E8, rmir=\E[4l,
    smcup=\E7\E[?47h, smir=\E[4h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smso=\E[7m,
```

If enabling `altscreen` in your .screenrc doesn't fix it, try adding these 2 lines to your .vimrc:

```
set t_ti=^[[?47h
set t_te=^[[?47l
```

(note that `^[` is escape, I typed `ctrl-v` `esc`)
Vim will echo ti to the terminal on startup and te on exit, instructing the shell/xterm/screen to switch screen buffers.

Comment: I don't have these defined but altscreen worked for me. So to get it working outside screen, I need to infocmp ? I can make the changes to my vimrc though. Thanks

Comment: if the terminfo for your current TERM has `rmcup` and `smcup` set, Vim should echo those sequences at start and exit to switch screen buffers.  If it doesn't have those defined, you can try using a different TERM, modify the terminfo for your current TERM, or add those sequences to .vimrc.